# SNS message does not reflect in SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-sqs, aws-cli, amazon-sns

We want to publish a message from SNS Topic to SQS Queue but without enabling "Everybody" check box in Principal element of SQS queue. i.e. we want to restrict the access to limited aws-user/ aws-account.

Currently, when we publish a message via SNS TOPIC using AWS CLI we get a message ID however the message doesn't reflect in SQS queue.
When we enable the "Everybody" checkbox of the principal element in SQS permission the message gets reflected.
We don't want to enable "Everybody" checkbox as this seems to be risky as it allows everyone to publish message to the queue.

**just FYI:-**

SNS TOPIC, SQS QUEUE and Subscription is successful.
we only have readonly access to AWS Web console and we have to implement these services using AWS CLI

we added **SendMessage** permission using below command.

**aws sqs add-permission --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com//sampleq --label SendMessageFromSampleQ --aws-account-ids <12 digit account ID> --actions SendMessage**

We also tried to modify the permission using **set-queue-attributes**

**aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com//sampleq --attributes file://test.json**

where test.json consists of NotPrincipal element with the specific account id which should be allowed to send message.

When we set the Effect paramter as "Allow", the message is reflected in SQS queue and when we set Effect as "Deny" the message is not reflected in SQS queue.

AWS Reference Link for notPrincipal:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html

We want to know the best practice or best possible solution which doesn't compromise with security aspect while sending a message from SNS to SQS.

Also, in case our understanding w.r.t. "Everybody" checkbox in SQS permission or Effect:"Allow" parameter used in "notPrincipal" json element is incorrect please help us understand.

Any suggestions/references would be really helpful.

**Thanks in Advance,**

Rohan Shetty